# How to change list LI item background color

Tags: html, css, sass

How to set background-color for entire

list item (including bullets)

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

.li:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

but this way it doesn't change background color under bullets

Comment: Remember **li** is your tag component, not **class** so you should not use **.li** you should use **li**. Remove **dot** from **.li**. And also add **list-style-position: inside;** on to the **ul**. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why it breaks everything after adding multiple `<p>` tags and `<spans>` is because the `<p>` tags are the block elements, hence their default behavior is to take a complete line or start from the new line. If you want to add multiple `<p>` tags inside a single`<li>` tag then you should specify  `<p>` tag as inline-block while `<spans>` are inline elements by default.

look the HTML in which i have entered 1 `<p>` and `<span>` tag in each `<li>`

```
   <ul>
      <li>
        <p>this is nested paragraph inside li</p>
        <span>hellooo</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>this is my second nested paragraph</p>
        <span>hellooooo</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>this is third nested paragraph</p>
        <span>Hellooooooooooooo</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

right now its breaks everything but when I will specify `<p>` tag as inline-block, everything will look fine.

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside
}
li{
  background-color: gray;
  color: white
}
li:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
p{
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add `list-style-position: inside;` to the ul

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  padding: .5rem
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

for styling the list including bullets, there's a property called list-style-position, which defines whether the bullets will be considered as inside the list item or out the list item.

Your HTML will look like

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

and css will be

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside
}
li{
  background-color: gray;
  color: white
}
li:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

remember that `<li>` is a type selector so there's no need to use (.li) in CSS file.
for a live demo, check out my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/poRXpBe)

Comment: it works fine but breaks everything if I have multiline <li>. .e.g. few <p> or <span> inside <li>

Comment: I have posted another answer regarding your problem, don't forget to upvote if it helps you. Thanks